# Configuring Logger in Razor Pages application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-logging

I'm trying to get up to speed on ASP.NET Core Razor Pages so I was trying to step through the article [Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.0).

A lot of the documentation I've been finding is not panning out for one reason or another, and I didn't get very far through this article either. Near the top, it contains the following code snippet.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.AddConsole();
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

But that code just won't even compile for me.

[image]

I've tried *Ctrl+.* and everything else I could think of, but `WebHostBuilderContext` just doesn't have the methods shown in this article.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should try reading further through the documentation before quitting; directly under the code snippets is the following statement: *"`LoggerFactory` and `AddConsole` require a `using` statement for `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`."* Additionally, if you followed the link near the top of the page to [View or download sample code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/logging/index/samples) you would have found complete working code examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are also using .NET Core 3,

the sample works for me out of the box with no issues if i create a new ASP.NET Core MVC app in VS 2019 selecting .NET Core 3,

you might not have created a project in that way, are you sure you have this using at the top? if not, add this at top of program.cs and if does not resolve means you have to first add the reference to this assembly.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
```

Comment: Adding the `using` statement fixed it. I'm using the very latest version of Visual Studio, but I'm building a Razor Pages app and not MVC (that shouldn't matter). Don't understand why *Ctrl+.* wasn't smart enough to suggest the `using`.

Comment: @JonathanWood It's an extension method, which is complicated for IntelliSense to figure out. With VS2019 16.1, experimental support for more inclusive IntelliSense was added, but it is still opt-in even in 16.3.7 and must be enabled by checking "Show items from unimported namespaces (experimental)" under the C# IntelliSense options. I'm not entirely sure if even that will detect extension methods like that, however.

Comment: @Herohtar: Oh, that would explain it.